# Restrict traffic between servers on same VLAN

Tags: networking, cisco

Scenario:

Internet <----> Hardware firewall/router <----> Cisco Catalyst 3560 switch (2 VLANs)

What is the best way to restrict traffic between servers within the same VLAN?   Can I create ACL's on our switch for this?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Use firewalls on both machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With private vlans (pvlans) you can prevent hosts talking to each other even if they're in the same VLAN. There are [extensive docs in the Cisco website](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12.2_20_se/configuration/guide/swpvlan.html) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this - stuff between machines on the same VLAN won't be routed, thus won't go through your router.

You can put them on different VLANs, which is probably what you should do if you have a business or security reason to restrict traffic between them. Or you could use host-based firewalls, on one or both hosts, but that is a lot more to manage.

Comment: You can apply port or MAC address based ACL's though, right?

Comment: @Joe - If you do that, all you can do it explictly prevent them from communicating at all, right? You can't, say, filter everything except SSH, AFAIK.